# Setting up collision for large-scale model in Unreal Engine

Tags: objects, collision, unreal-engine

I was creating a large scene for use in the Unreal Engine, but I need proper collision physics and since Unreal Engine's collisions aren't suitable for large-scale objects, I have no idea how to go about doing it at this scale.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just scale the entire scene down, and then continue from there. This should work, because scaling down doesn't affect any of the objects themselves, but will then be able to do collision simulations in unreal. You could also just scale it down in Unreal.

Comment: I got every rooms measurements perfect for unreal, So scaling down wont affect it's measurements in anyway?

Comment: Not if it is scaled correctly

Comment: I tried scaling down in unreal and blender, No luck, While scaling down in blender it messed with measurements and made the rooms way too small plus the doorways

Comment: That's weird. You selected everything?

Comment: Yeah, everything was selected.

Comment: Is there a way to UCX_ everything fairly quick besides doing it to every wall and floor?